# Skipping instruction in ARM assembly

Tags: assembly, arm

Im not experienced in writing Assembly at all, so I have this rather easy to answer question I guess.

Having this simple loop:

```
mov r0,#3
loop:
   do some instructions
   ...
   last-instruction

subs r0,r0,#1
bne loop
afterloop:
```

If I understand well, this loop should decrease from 3 to 0 and stop (correct me if Im wrong).

However,in the last iteration when r0 == 0 I want to skip the `last-instruction` and step out of the loop. I presume there has to be some `cmp` if r0 equals 0 then jump to `afterloop`. But I guess there might be some easier way to achieve this.

**EDIT:**
One more question - what if there's more instructions to be skipped?

In C it would look like this:

```
int i = 3;
while (1) {
  foo();

  if (i == 0) break;
  skipped_func();
  --i;
}
```

Comment: please re-write your question or code using pseudo code that is very clear as to what you want to do where in the loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless the last instruction depends on r0 and/or modifies the CPSR, move the `subs` line one step before the last instruction and make the last instruction conditional with a NE condition. Like this:

```
mov r0,#3
loop:
   do some instructions
   ...


    subs r0,r0,#1
    last-instructionNE
bne loop
afterloop:
```

If the last instruction is a `mov`, make it a `movne`. If a `str`, make it a `strne`. And so forth.

This won't work if the last instruction already has an "s" postfix - modifies the flags. If it does, it'll ruin the zero flag and the `bne` won't work as expected. Also, if the last instruction relies on the value of r0 before the decrease, it also has to execute before the `subs`.

On ARM, unlike Intel, almost every instruction can be made conditional, not just B(ranch). Unless it's actually Thumb.

EDIT re: edit: you can make more than one instruction conditional that way. Alternatively, you can also replicate the same logic with jumps. Like this:

```
mov r0,#3
loop:
   do some instructions
   ...
    subs r0,r0,#1
    bz afterloop

   last-instructions
b loop
afterloop:
```

This is decidedly the "Intelish" style of assembly. Some claim it's easier to understand. For 2-3 conditional lines, I wouldn't bother. For 10+, I would. In the middle there's a gray zone. :)

`Bz` and `be` are synonyms. The logic is clearer this way - you're implicitly comparing r0 to 0.

In this scenario, last instructions can ruin the flags all they want. Reading from r0 would still give you the already-decreased value.

Comment: Ok, and if there are more instructions I need to make conditional every single one?

Comment: Can you maybe show this jump logic on an example in your answer please? Thanks!

Comment: And in Thumb2, you can just use IT* instructions to get conditionals.